# Webview windows 8 embedded Browser's keyboard doesn't scroll with the page. Touch pads

Tags: asp.net, windows-8, webview, microsoft-metro

I am using a windows 8 metro app with an embedded browser. When in this browser I load a asp.net web application. The issue occurs on a page like the registration page where I have numerous text fields. When the user gets down to the last few fields the keyboard blocks the fields.

On any other browser the keyboard pushes the web form above the keyboard but not in the embedded portal. It just hides the fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebView has it's own window handle and thus has "airspace" issues again the XAML background.  In order to deal with these issues, you need to determine when things like the keyboard or AppBar would obscure the WebView and modify its position manually.  You can see an example of this in [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7) where they apply an animation and a transform to the WebView to deal with the AppBar showing and hiding.

You need to do the same for the keyboard.  You can figure out when the Input Pane (soft keyboard) is going to show or hide and how much of the screen is going to be obscured using the [InputPane class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242255.aspx).